# Relationship between Ka and Kb

Tags: acid-base

> Considering the $K_\text{a}$ of the weak acid and the $K_\text{b}$ of the weak base that form the salt, we conclude that the solution will be acidic if $K_\text{b}$ > $K_\text{a}$ and basic if $K_\text{a}$ > $K_\text{b}$

I was wondering if anyone could clarify what the book is saying. 
My question is If we mix a solution with a $K_\text{b}$ of 0.1 with a solution with a $K_\text{a}$ of 0.001 would the final solution be acidic or basic?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a solution of mix of a weak acid/base and it's alkaline/acidic salt in molar ratio 1:1, then

- The solution is acidic, if $K_\mathrm{a} \gt K_\mathrm{b}$, like acetic acid + sodium acetate(alkaline base)
- The solution is alkalic(ine)/basic, if $K_\mathrm{a} \lt K_\mathrm{b}$, like ammonium chloride ( acidic salt) + ammonia(base)

Note that $$\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{w}&=\ce{[H+][OH-]} \\
K_\mathrm{a}&=\frac{\ce{[H+][A-]}}
{\ce{[HA]}}  \\
K_\mathrm{b}&=\frac{\ce{[HA][OH-]}}
{\ce{[A-]}}  \\
&=\frac{\ce{[HA]  K_\mathrm{w}}}{\ce{[A-][H+]}}  \\
&=\frac{\ce{  K_\mathrm{w}}}{K_\mathrm{a}}  \\
K_\mathrm{w}&=K_\mathrm{a} \cdot K_\mathrm{b} \\
\end{align}$$

Similarly, if there is such a 1:1 (molar amount) solution of an acid and a base, that are not in the mutual relation acid/salt or base/salt, the above is valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ka and kb are related as -
Kw = ka × kb
Here, kw is equlibrium constant of self ionisation of water. At a particular temperature kw is constant. E.g value of kw at 25 °C is 10^(-14).
So, ka and kb are inversely propotional . Acidic and basic strength is inversely proportional to ka and kb respectively bescause measure of its strength is negative of log(ka or kb).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we mix a solution with a Kb of 0.1 with a solution with a Ka of 0.001 would the final solution be acidic or basic

Comment: That is s wrong question. Ka is a constant of acidic form of a compound, independently in if it exists as an acid or is neutralised, becoming a basic salt , or can be in any middle step.